# Creating empty string for 'rep:glob'

Tags: java, jackrabbit, jcr

To restrict node access to user(using `principalbased.ACL`), tried with following snippet, but turns ineffective:

```
Map<String, Value> restrictions = new HashMap<String, Value>(); 
//Apply privilege to user to have read only access to root folder 
restrictions.put("rep:nodePath", valueFactory.createValue(ROOT, PropertyType.PATH)); 
restrictions.put("rep:glob", valueFactory.createValue("")); 
accessControlList.addEntry(userPrincipal, privileges, true  , restrictions); 
accessControlManager.setPolicy(accessControlList.getPath(), accessControlList);
```

Is there any other way to set ***rep:glob*** property to `""`?

When I provide access to root('/'), it should access only that. Instead all the nodes under root are accessible to user.

Comment: What do you mean by *ineffective* and what are you expecting?

Comment: I meant it, coz, rep:glob set to empty string acts like '*'. Following snippets effect is identical:

restrictions.put("rep:glob", valueFactory.createValue(""));

restrictions.put("rep:glob", valueFactory.createValue("*"));

Comment: Sorry if I'm not into the right context but I cannot understand what you are intending to say exactly. Could you please tell me what are you expecting in terms of *security* and *restriction*.
What are you expecting for the node to behave like when you set an empty `String` (`""`) to the `rep:glob` property?

Comment: Simple:
1. Login as super user  
2. Create new user
3. Provide permission to access certain path, say '/1/TEMP to newly created user
4. Now try to retrieve new session from newly created user
5. Workspace access denied. Because with newly created user credentials, not able to read the root node of workspace.
6. Try providing access to root node(with above snippet), exposes all available nodes to user in the workspace.

QUESTION is how to restrict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even this(http://jackrabbit.apache.org/api/2.2/org/apache/jackrabbit/core/security/authorization/GlobPattern.html) pattern didn't work for root. Anyways I have used other approach to skip root access check, while getting user. Need to provide SimpleWorkspaceAccessManager in SecurityManager tag.

Answer (score 1):

When you don't provide the `rep:glob` property while restricting principal access, the default ACL effects the whole subtree of the target node. 
Thus the optional `rep:glob` propety will save you time of creating restrictions on every path you want to limit the policy and it accepts JCR [`Value`s](http://www.day.com/maven/javax.jcr/javadocs/jcr-2.0/javax/jcr/Value.html) and the passed `String` instance while creating this `Value` will have below effect on node/subnodes restriction when appliedon  the ndoe with path "/foo" :

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  rep:glob value   |                            Effect                            |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        null       |               matches /foo and all its children              |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  "" (Empty String)| matches "/foo" only                                          |
  * (wildcard)     | all descendants                                              |
  /*bar            | all childrens which path ends with "bar"                     |
  /*/bar           | all non-direct descendants of "/foo" named "bar"             |
  /bar*            | all childrens which paths begin with "bar"                   |
  *bar             | all siblings and descendants of "/foo" that begin with "bar" |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If the the restriction is not applied only for your target node, then there should be some mistake somewhere, and you may need to post the whole code snippet for further help.